# How to take care the source from being stolen?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using visual studio 2012 and SVN (tortoise) repository. I want to block some developers access to some source files, but I need the solution project compile ok. So I can't quit any file from it, and I don't want to use compiled dll. I want to know if exist some software /plug in / app  that to controls some access permission to view/get files into VS. Any Idea ?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to compile source without access to the source. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You could obfuscate the source code. (e.g. give variables cryptic names)
If this is an option, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937734/is-there-any-program-that-obfuscates-c-sharp-source-code).